# With Nginx, how do I preserve the client's IP address when using proxy_pass?

Tags: php, nginx, proxypass

I have a simple `proxy_pass` in NGINX that looks like this:

```
location / {
    proxy_pass https://foo.bar/API/;
    rewrite ^/API/(.*) /$1;
}
```

When I print `$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];` (PHP) on the final destination (reached after the redirect) I see the server's IP instead of the client's IP.

I tried to add

```
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header REMOTE_ADDR $remote_addr;
```

to the `location /` in order to preserve the client's IP, but that doesn't work (I keep seeing the server's own IP).

How can I preserve the client's IP after a `proxy_pass`?

Comment: With the proxy header set (X-Real-IP) check `$_SERVER['X-REAL-IP']` in php.

Comment: @Scott I get `undefined index`. Tried both `X-REAL-IP` and `X-Real-IP`.